# HTML Link which would drop down a menu working like a form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Bit of a confusing one here as I'm not sure what this would be called?...

If anyone is familiar with Facebooks layout, I am trying to code a similar item as on the side of the "comments" boxes or "status" boxes where you have the "DOWNWARD ARROW" icon, which once clicked, drops down a menu (Similar to a drop down menu but a bit more hard work included). Only issue is, once an item in the menu is clicked, I need to perform an action... Such as:

```
<?php
if($_POST['delete']){
mysql_query"Do the query";
}
```

Just in the same way as a form would work. Is there an easy or simpler way to do this rather than mess with loads of CSS and JS codes? Just to get a simple "arrow" styled icon, which drops into a menu, with each item selected working as a form submit button?

P.S: Already attempted using a drop down select box, didn't work. Also tried adding an icon in to it, didn't work. Have attempted using a drop down navigation menu, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just use a `select` with some simple javascript, as such:

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

As soon as the user selects an option, the form will submit.

To elaborate a little, here's an example:

```
<?php
    // If form submitted, check value and do work...
    if (isset($_POST['myselect'])) {
        if ($_POST['myselect'] == 'delete') {
           echo "User selected Delete!!!";
        }
        //elseif ...                    
    }
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <select name="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option>...</option>
        <option value="delete">Delete</option>
        <option value="other">Other task...</option>
    </select>
</form>
```